After creating an address on the base chain with the same address as the mainnet, how can I transfer assets from the base chain?[safe-core]
I deployed an address on the base chain with the same address as the mainnet. Currently, the following methods don't support withdrawals:
1.The base chain page doesn't show this asset.
2.The Dapp CSV feature doesn't support it.
3.The New Transition's Transition Builder doesn't support it.
How do I transfer my assets using Safe CLI? I'm not a developer and I don't understand GitHub and code.

we've already covered this question here: ETH address under OP Network
Hope it helps; Best, Louis

I tried，but infura don't support base chain for most users，What should I do？

@StereoZhang there are other providers like https://chainstack.com/build-better-with-base/
